# Plot the two matrices as colormaps on the same graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two numpy multi dimmensional matrices that have five features each like this

```
 array1 = array([ 1. ,  0.97572023,  0.97671645,  0.99772446,
    0.99326534,  0.94841498]....) 
 array2 = array([ 0.97572023,  1.        ,  0.99343976,  0.9844228 ,
    0.9880037 ,  0.96203135]....)
```

I want to plot these multidimesional matrices as colormaps and label each feature on the graph..Whats the best way to plot multidimensional array.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm as cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet', 30)
cax = ax1.imshow(df, interpolation="nearest", cmap=cmap)
ax1.grid(True)
plt.title('Abalone Feature Correlation')
labels=['feat1','feat2','feat3','feat4','feat5']
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels,fontsize=6)
ax1.set_yticklabels(labels,fontsize=6)
# Add colorbar, make sure to specify tick locations to match desired ticklabels
fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,.75,.8,.85,.90,.95,1])
plt.show()
```

I am using this function but the features are not displayed properly..The labels and the points are not displayed correctly.Any help?

Comment: What is the relation between `array1`, `array2` and `df`, and what are their shapes? What is your output, and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: @fuglede array is the covariance of the matrix and the array is the correlation of the matrix .. df is the just the same matrix I was testing for the colormap

Comment: I see; if the arrays simply represent 5x5 matrices, calling them multi-dimensional is confusing. If I understand the question correctly, you also only want to plot one of the two arrays?

Comment: I want to plot both the correlation and the covariance array on the same plot with each feature as a label

Comment: How would that work -- as they can't overlap directly, would you want something like one `imshow`-plot above the other, but on the same figure, or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Instructing matplotlib to use specific ticks for the `imshow` plot ensures that labels appear in the right places,

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm as cm

# Generate some data for the sake of example
array = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (5, 5))

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet', 30)


cax = ax1.imshow(array, interpolation="nearest", cmap=cmap)
ax1.grid(True)
plt.title('Abalone Feature Correlation')
labels=['feat1', 'feat2', 'feat3', 'feat4', 'feat5']

# Explicitly set ticks for the plot
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(labels)))
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(len(labels)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels,fontsize=6)
ax1.set_yticklabels(labels,fontsize=6)

# Add colorbar, make sure to specify tick locations to match desired ticklabels
fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,.75,.8,.85,.90,.95,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]